# Object ContentDocumentLink query not working as expected

Tags: rest-api, chatter, chatter-file

I am running following query on ContentDocumentLink object using admin token.

```
/services/data/v32.0/queryAll?q=SELECT+ContentDocumentId,Id,IsDeleted,LinkedEntityId,ShareType,SystemModstamp,Visibility+FROM+ContentDocumentLink+WHERE+LinkedEntityId+=+'xx'+AND+IsDeleted+=+true
```

It is returning me zero records even after deleting a ContentDocumentLink record of the LinkedEntityId given in the query. Is the ContentDocumentLink records are hard-deleted and soft-deleted ? If that is the case, what is the need for IsDeleted system field. Kindly help. Thanks